# How to change roles and permissions in runtime in Spring-boot using SpringWebSecurity

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have same "projects" and same users in database in my Spring-boot webapp. Users access to projects using URLs like:

```
 http: // server / project / 1
 http: // server / project / 2
 ...
 http: // server / project / x
```

Where "x" is the project ID as type long.

Different users have different privileges to projects, eg .:

- User1 has ADMIN role in "Project1"
- User2 has USER role in "Project1"
- User3 has the USER role in "Projec1"
- User1 has USER role in "Project2"
- User2 has ADMIN role in "Project2"
- User3 has the USER role in "Projec2"

Some user add new project "Project3" and grant access to this project to User1 and User2 with the USER and User3 roles with the ADMIN role.

In database I have table USERS (user list) and table AUTHORITIES (privileges of each user) but I don't know how to link privileges, users and "projects".

```
package pl.pecynki.testapp;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        handler.setUseReferer(false);
        return handler;
    }   

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/project/**")
                    .hasRole("USER");
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/project/**/edit/")
                    .hasRole("ADMIN");
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/project/new")
                    .hasRole("SUPERADMIN");
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/notice_form")
                .authenticated();

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/**")
                    .permitAll();

        http
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(successHandler());
        http
            .formLogin()
                .permitAll();
        http
            .logout()
                .permitAll();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
           .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password,enabled from users where username=?")
           .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username,authority from authorities where username=?");
    }

}
```

Comment: No, but now this is not my priority.

Comment: Did you find your way through this please?